# How to pass data to a widget inside of another widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I was able to pass the data `widget.value` from the `FirstPage` to `SecondPage`. There's a widget called `thirdWidget` inside `SecondPage`.
How do I pass `widget.value` to `thirdWidget`?

```
class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => FirstPageState();
}

class FirstPageState extends State< FirstPage > {
  final myController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    myController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First Route'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(
            controller: myController,
            decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: "Enter a number"),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          ),

          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("show text"),
            onPressed: () {
                    return Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => ThirdRoute(
                              selectedDate: selectedDate,
                              value: myController.text,
                            )),
                  );
              },
             );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}



class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String value;

  ThirdRoute({Key key, this.value})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  SecodpageState createState() => SecodpageState();
}

class SecodpageState extends State< SecondPage > {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Calendar Page"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("${widget.value}"),
          Row(
            children: thirdWidget(),
          ),
          Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: Text('Go back!'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


List<Widget> thirdWidget() {
   return Text("${widget.value}”)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your `SecondPage`

```
Row(
  children: thirdWidget(widget.value),
)
```

And update your `thirdWidget` like:

```
List<Widget> thirdWidget(var data) {
  // data is widget.value
  return [];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass that info into the state class. Something like that:

```
class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String value;

  ThirdRoute({Key key, this.value})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  SecodpageState createState() => SecodpageState(value);
}

class SecodpageState extends State< SecondPage > {
  final String value;

  SecodpageState(this.value);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Calendar Page"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("${widget.value}"),
          Row(
            children: thirdWidget(),
          ),
          Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: Text('Go back!'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


List<Widget> thirdWidget() {
   return Text(value);
}
```

Comment: this one isn't working Text(value); is return value is undefined.